# How is $ n^{log(n)} > n^c $ always for any c?

Tags: asymptotics

I was going through the questions in [MIT quiz : Question 2 g](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/oldquizzes/solutions/quiz1-s2011-sol.pdf)
and I found this
[image]

How is  $ n^{log(n)} > n^c $ always for any c ?

what if c > log(n) ?

Comment: For the future (and past questions) please transcribe images into text or LaTeX. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In these exercises, you are asked to compare functions only according to their asymptotic behavior.

In this case, $c$ is a constant function of $n$, while $\log(n)$ is a function of $n$ that approaches $+\infty$ when $n$ becomes large.

So, $c > \log(n)$ can only hold for finitely many values of $n$.